# Cast Array of Bytes to UInt8Array

Tags: python, pyarrow

I have a pyarrow [BinaryArray](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.BinaryArray.html) with exactly one byte at each location. These bytes are not UTF8, but "actual" binary data.

I'd like to cast this into a [UInt8Array](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.UInt8Array.html), but that seems difficult.

- `array_of_bytes.cast(pa.uint8())` fails with `ArrowInvalid: Failed to parse string: '�' as a scalar of type uint8`
- [`UInt8Array`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.UInt8Array.html) does not (seem to) have a constructor usable on its own
- I have taken a look at a[`FixedSizeBinaryArray`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.FixedSizeBinaryArray.html), but that also does not seem to help

This Python workaround does the job, but is incredibly slow:

```py
pa.array([int.from_bytes(scalar.as_py()) for scalar in array_of_bytes], pa.uint8())
```

Is there a way to achieve this directly in pyarrow?

---

**EDIT:** this is a minimal, reproducible example:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
array_of_bytes = pa.array([bytes([i]) for i in range(256)], pa.binary())
array_of_bytes.cast(pa.uint8())  # this fails
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] you can add to your post?

Comment: Sure, see above :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BinaryArray is made of 3 buffers:

- one buffer keeping track of null/missing values (None in your case, all values are present)
- one buffer keeping track of the offset of each bytes (basically their size)
- one buffer keeping track of all the bytes, appended to one another

In your case you just want to take the last buffer and convert it to a UInt8Array. You'll also have to provide a "mask" buffer to tell which values are null/missing (None in your case since all values are present).

```py
pa.UInt8Array.from_buffers(
    pa.uint8(),
    len(array_of_bytes),
    [None, array_of_bytes.buffers()[2]]
)
```